# Why is Google autoload loading more than what I'm telling it too?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to autoload Google Maps 3, JQuery core (1.3.2) and JQuery UI (1.7.2).

So I am using the following URL:

```
http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
"modules":[
{name:"maps",version:3,other_params:"sensor=false"},
{"name":"jquery","version":"1.3.2"},
{"name":"jqueryui","version":"1.7.2"}
]}
```

However, if you go to that URL, it appears that in addition to what I want to load, it's also loading: scriptaculous, feeds, and books

Any ideas when the Google autoload is loading more than what I'm telling it to load?

Comment: shouldn't you be asking google?

Comment: Since this is a programming question, I figured maybe someone knew here ... or, maybe it's a mistake on my part. Nonetheless, Stackoverflow is a forum for developers. I figured maybe another developer would know

Comment: Looks like even if you don't provide any modules it's still loading scriptaculous, feeds and books:  http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[]}

Answer (score 0):

You can always load the JavaScript files directly from google. See

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/

For the above it would be like

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```